# IClientMessageInspector in Silverlight 3.0?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, wcf, soapheader, custom-headers

I'm trying to secure a data service using SOAP headers in Silverlight.
I thought i had found the answer in **IClientMessageInspector**. Unfortunately by default it seems this isn't supported, as creating a SL project adds a reference to System.ServiceModel v.2, and this interface wasn't added until v.3.

Looking around online, every blog says that IClientMessageInspector will not work **with Silverlight 2.0**. But none of them mention anything about SL 3.0.

So the question becomes, is there any way to use the IClientMessageInspector as of SL v 3.0? Or is this functionality still MIA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... I think i have found a workaround to this, in this blog posting.

**[IClientMessageInspector implementation for Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlightws/archive/2008/10/20/new-web-services-features-in-sl2-rtw.aspx)**

I'm still in the process of porting it into my project, but it looks awfully promising...
Will post back.

Comment: It works in the sample code, but not yet in mine; which just means there's some piece i'm missing. Will continue to post updates as i find stuff out.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Definitely recommended if you are looking to do the same thing.